# Can get variables to work in setting a recipientRestrictionFilter

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

We have an Exchange Management scope per country, where we try to adjust the Recipient filter. Have created following code:

```
Foreach ($Obj in $Scopes) {
    $Scope = Get-ManagementScope $Obj.Name
    Write-Host "Retrieved $($Scope)"
    $Country = ($Scope.Name -split "_")[1]
    Write-Host "Retrieved $($Country)"
    $CountryCode = $Co | ? {$_.Country -like "$Country*"}
    Write-Host "Retrieved $($CountryCode.Alpha3) for $($Country)" -ForegroundColor Green
    $Filter = {((CountryOrRegion -eq $Country) -or (Name -Like "$($CountryCode.Alpha3)_*"))}
    Set-ManagementScope $($Scope.name) -recipientRestrictionFilter $Filter
}
```

What we get is this
`((-not(CountryOrRegion -eq $Country) -or (Name -Like "$($CountryCode.Alpha3)_*"))`, while it should be `((CountryOrRegion -eq 'USA') -or (Name -like 'USA_*'))`
We have more than 50 managementscopes to adjust, and do not want to adjust them manually.
The $co array contains the countries along with their alpha-2 and alpha-3 country codes.
Any tips are welcome.

Comment: Use `$filter = "CountryOrRegion -eq '$Country' -or Name -Like '$($CountryCode.Alpha3)_*'"`

Comment: Tried that, gives the warning: WARNING: The command completed successfully but no settings of 'EMEA_Estonia' have been modified. The management scope was indeed not modified.